# boton dentro de un map aparece solo en la primera imagen

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

Tengo un componente el cual refleja las imágenes que el usuario esta a punto de subir al servidor, este es el componente encargado de manejar dicha logica:

```
const Preview_image: FC<{ image: File[] }> = ({ image }) => {

  const theme = useTheme();
  const [activeStep, setActiveStep] = useState<number>(0);

  const handleNext = () => {
    setActiveStep((prevActiveStep) => prevActiveStep + 1);
  };

  const handleBack = () => {
    setActiveStep((prevActiveStep) => prevActiveStep - 1);
  };

  const deleteFile = (item: File) => {
    console.log(item)
  };

  const isVideo = new RegExp("video/*");

  const classes = stylePublisher();
  return (
    <div className={classes.containerPreview}>
      <SwipeableViews
        axis={theme.direction === "rtl" ? "x-reverse" : "x"}
        index={activeStep}
        onChangeIndex={handleNext}
      >
        {image.map((item: File | any, index: number) => (
          <TabPanel key={index} value={activeStep} index={index}>
            <LightTooltip title="QUITAR"> //boton que aparece solo en la primer imagen
              <IconButton
                onClick={() => deleteFile(item)}
                className={classes.ButtonDeleteFile}
              >
                <HighlightOffRoundedIcon />
              </IconButton>
             </LightTooltip>
            {isVideo.test(item.type) ? (
              <video controls className={classes.video}>
                <source src={URL.createObjectURL(item)} />
              </video>
            ) : (
              <img
                title={item.name}
                className={classes.image}
                alt={item.name}
                src={URL.createObjectURL(item)}
              />
            )}
          </TabPanel>
        ))}
      </SwipeableViews>
      <MobileStepper
        variant="dots"
        steps={image.length}
        position="static"
        activeStep={activeStep}
        nextButton={
          <Button
            size="small"
            onClick={handleNext}
            disabled={activeStep === image.length - 1}
          >
            Siguiente
            {theme.direction === "rtl" ? (
              <KeyboardArrowLeft />
            ) : (
              <KeyboardArrowRight />
            )}
          </Button>
        }
        backButton={
          <Button size="small" onClick={handleBack} disabled={activeStep === 0}>
            {theme.direction === "rtl" ? (
              <KeyboardArrowRight />
            ) : (
              <KeyboardArrowLeft />
            )}
            Volver
          </Button>
        }
      />
    </div>
  );
};

export default Preview_image;
```

el `LightTooltip` contiene el botón que utilizo para mostrar sobre la imagen para que el usuario pueda eliminar esa imagen, mi problema es que solamente aparece en la primer imagen, si yo subo dos imágenes el botón aparece en la primera pero se va con ella cuando cambio a la segunda, se supone que debería haber un botón para cada imagen así el usuario puede borrar cualquier imagen, no se que es lo que estaría causando el problema.